# NSAttributeString Wrapping issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.6, nsattributedstring

I am trying to set attribute text to a label. The attributes seems to be a working the font as well as the color.

Only issue I am facing is the wrapping of lines. The Size of the UILabel is (200,300) with numberofLines=0. So with this it should wrap the lines, but it is not happening so.

```
   NSMutableString *title=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSRange range1;
    NSRange range2;
    NSRange range3;



        NSString *str1=@"ABCD EFGHI klm";
        [title appendString:str1];
        range1=NSMakeRange(0, str1.length);


        NSString *str2=@"PQRSSSS ";
        [title appendString:str2];
        range2=NSMakeRange(range1.length, str2.length);


        NSString *str3=@"1235 2347 989034 023490234 90";
        [title appendString:str3];
        range3=NSMakeRange(range2.location+range2.length, str3.length);


    NSMutableAttributedString *attributeText=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title];
    [attributeText setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:color1,NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[self getStlylishItalicFont:13.0] ,NSFontAttributeName,nil] range:range1];
    [attributeText setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:color2,NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[self getStylishFont:13.0] ,NSFontAttributeName,nil] range:range2];
    [attributeText setAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:color3,NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[self getStylishBoldFont:13.0] ,NSFontAttributeName,nil] range:range3];

    self.myTextLabel.attributedText=attributeText;
```

UILabel is displayed like this, even though the height is 300.

*ABCD EFGHI klm* PQRSSSS **1235 234 ...**

Comment: Does it wrap if you insert \n in the string? Just for test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you set your UILabel's line break mode attribute to the one you desired like so:

```
UILabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```

Or if you are using Interface Builder, you can do it there.

Comment: you also need to do
`label.numberOfLines = 0`

Answer (score 5):

What you need is the NSParagraphStyle attribute :

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 1;

//Now add this to your attributes dictionary for the key NSParagraphStyleAttributeName eg,
```

`@{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle,...}`

On an unrelated note you know its better to create dictionaries in the modern Objective-c format. Whenever I don't, my mentor get's angry. That would look something like this :

```
[attributeText setAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:color1, NSFontAttributeName:[self getStlylishItalicFont:13.0], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragraphStyle, }];
//The trailing comma in the dictionary definition is not at typo it is important.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you set the numberoflines to 1.Because wrapping makes sense but number of lines 0 doesnt make sense.. and also you have to set proper frame for label.

Comment: setting numberOfLines to zero is actually the proper way to set it to "unlimited number of lines" ... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html

Answer (score 0):

I think so u are facing the problem with the uilabel increasing the height , If u need the multiple lines in label then u have to give the property of havin numberoflines=0; after that u have to resize the label frame according to the size of text u are giving to the label.

Please check the below code i may be useful to u,

```
        NSString *someText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrFulldetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"MessageText"]];
        CGSize constraintSize;
        constraintSize.width = 300.0f;
        constraintSize.height =100000;
        CGSize stringSize =[someText sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 17] constrainedToSize: constraintSize lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        CGRect rect ;
        rect = CGRectMake(10, 150, 210, 20+stringSize.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

along with setting:

```
    self.myTextLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    self.myTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

You might also need to set your label's layout constraints to it's superview.  I ran into this when I neglected to pin my label's trailing constraint to the my label's superview.